# Unable to query consul DNS interface from host

Tags: docker, dns, consul

I am able to query the rest service of my remote consul container ie.

```
curl my-ip:8500/v1/catalog/services

    {"consul":[],"nginx-80":[],"redis":[]}

curl my-ip:8500/v1/catalog/service/redis

    [{"Node":"consul","Address":"172.17.0.3","ServiceID":"954f32f077ed:redis:6379","ServiceName":"redis","ServiceTags":null,"ServiceAddress":"","ServicePort":32768}]
```

But when I try the dns interface of consul

```
dig @my-ip -p 8600 redis.service.consul

    ; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @45.33.119.251 -p 8600 redis.service.consul
    ; (1 server found)
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I'm not sure if the format of my query is incorrect or how I started the container has an issue.

Comment: Consul's docker DNS port defaults to 8600. Did you remap it to port 53 as recommended in the documentation? https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/

Comment: This means that 8600 is not connectable. make sure the socket is open and that you didn't remap it to something else.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Consul configuration to see if you have don't have your `client_addr` or `addresses.dns` setting set.

If you don't have an `addresses.dns` entry set, then it defaults to `client_addr`. `client_addr` defaults to `127.0.0.1`, so it would only be available on the loopback address. If you're running Consul inside of Docker (for example, if you're working off of https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-consul-docker/tree/main/datacenter-deploy-service-discovery like I was) you might be deceived into thinking that you have it all set up correctly, especially because your netstat shows TCP and UDP listeners on 0.0.0.0:8600, but you still won't be able to connect to it from outside the container.

**References**

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/config/config-files#dns

> `dns` - The DNS server. Defaults to `client_addr`

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/config/config-files#client_addr

> `client_addr` Equivalent to the -client command-line flag.

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/config/cli-flags#_client

> `-client` - The address to which Consul will bind client interfaces, including the HTTP and DNS servers. By default, this is "127.0.0.1", allowing only loopback connections.

---

So, you should be able to either set your `client_addr` to `0.0.0.0` (or whatever IP you're trying to bind to), or add an `addresses.dns` setting like this:

```
{
    ...
    "addresses": {
         "dns": "0.0.0.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

to configure Consul to respond to DNS queries coming in from outside the loopback address.